# Euler Lagrange of a 2D integral

Tags: integration, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I need to find the euler lagrange solution, meaning the function $f$ that minimizes:

$$\min_f \int_{}^{} \int_{}^{} \: (\nabla f(x,y) - \nabla s(x,y))^2  \: \: dxdy $$

When we fully know $s(x,y)$, and we know $f(x,y)$ on the boundaries of the integral.

Comment: Hint: what's your Lagrangian? What's its derivative with respect to $\nabla f$? (The substitution $u=f-s$ would also help.)

Comment: What do you mean by "with respect to"? Do you mean the derivative of ∇ by x? or by y?

Comment: "The derivative of $A$ with respect to $B$" means $\partial A/\partial B$. Calling the Lagrangian $L$, work out $\partial L/\partial\nabla f$.

Comment: If we define u(x,y)=(∇f-∇s), then the EL formula here is:
 ∂L/∂u=0 , since there is no dependance on second derivative of the Largangian by u'. So we need to do something like ∂L/∂u * = 2*(∇f-∇s)=0, but this is the wrong answer.
However if we define u=f-s then L= (∇u)^2 then ∂L/∂u =2(∇u)(∇^2u)=0 and that means that either ∇f-∇s=0 or ∇^2f-∇^2s=0

Comment: The correct argument is$$0=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u}-\nabla\frac{\partial}{\partial\nabla u}\right)\left(\nabla u\right)^2=-2\nabla^2u.$$